# Mandrill is ghosting accounts or am i incorrect - it says delivered however mandrill did not even tried to send emails

Tags: mandrill

I am using free mandrill account and sending email via using template and API

When i send message it returns okay it is sent as status

However even after several days there is still no smtp events at mandrill interface and the email is not arrived

So i am 100% suree mandrill is ghosting accounts

Or there is something else that i do not know?

Thank you for answers

PS: At the beginning emails were arriving but after some point no smtp events and no emails ever arrived even though no error message parsed. Also when i send to non existing email no bounce message returned.

Also account reputation is 61 : excellent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes i believe mandrill certainly ghosting accounts

After trying with several accounts i am now sure of it

Even if you send to non existing gmail email, it says delivered in its interface

However it should have displayed hard bounced

So beware of their free service. I believe this is not an ethical way of working. People would think that their emails are arriving however they are ghosted and mandrill did not even try to send them and yet displays delivered

Answer (score 1):

Have you check it on Mandrill account? It shows all the report at outbound tag. The reason is, a queued response in the Mandrill API is not the same as a queued response from a recipient server.

When you send a message through Mandrill, you first relay it to Mandrill, Mandrill processes it, and then Mandrill relays it to the recipient server. This all happens quite quickly, but the two relaying steps are separate and distinct. The KB article you've linked to is providing additional details on that last step, relaying to recipient servers, not a queued status for the Mandrill API.

There are a number of reasons the Mandrill API may respond with queued including if you've added attachments or if you're sending to a bunch of recipients in a single API call.

Without seeing the actual API call that's being made, it's hard to say why you're getting a queued response. But if you're using the sample messages/send API call, you'll want to remove all of the optional parameters that you're not actually setting. For example, the sample has fake attachments, and a subaccount specified. The attachment will cause the call to be processed async. The subaccount probably doesn't exist, and would then cause the call to fail. So if that's the case, try removing all of those optional params. If not, please provide the API call you're making with sensitive data redacted (API key, actual email addresses).

Comment: Yes i checked everything and everything is displayed correctly fine. So they show they are sent, but nothing, actually they are not sent account is ghosted

Comment: Then its a serious problem. If you want to confirm again then you can use Mandrill message's API here https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html#method=info ,  go to **message calls/info** just use your key and message id which was recently sent and click on **try it**. Sometimes it gives response instantly sometimes take up to 24 hours to give correct status of the message.

Comment: Hi @MonsterMMORPG You can also use Java API for this, like `MandrillApi mandrillApi = new MandrillApi(MailConstants.MANDRILL_API_KEY);MandrillMessageInfo info = null;
  try {
   info = mandrillApi.messages().info(id);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   throw new MailServiceException(ErrorCodes.ERROR_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, ErrorCodes.ERROR_MESSAGE_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
  }
  return info;`

Comment: well i checked in that time, they ghost it. it is not an error. simply it shows as perfectly sent, but ghosted never sent